# avoid subscriptions everywhere

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm working on an ap which will have to call a lot of different WS.
WS responses will be used in several places.
Problem is i'm starting to get a lot of subscribe() everywhere.

An example of a service :

```
public getAllNotifications(): Observable<Notification[]> {
  return this.http.get(config.ws_url + `/api/user/notification/all`)
      .map((res: Response) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .map((json) => {
        return plainToClass(Notification, json);
      }).share();
}
```

And then everytime that I want to use this notification list I have to subscribe() to it.

My Notification component is :

```
  constructor(private notifService: NotificationService) {
    super();

    this.notifService.getAllNotifications().subscribe(notif => {
      this.notifications = notif;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  private deleteNotif(notif: Notification): void {
    this.notifService.deleteNotification(notif.getId()).subscribe(json => {
      if (json.status === 200) {
        this.notifications.splice(this.notifications.findIndex(curNotif => curNotif.getId() === notif.getId()), 1);
      }
    });
  }
```

I guess that there's a problem cause I think I'm not supposed to subscribe so much, but can't see the goot way to use this.
Any idea or link which explain the good way to use it?
Thx

Comment: That's pretty much just how it works, yeah.

Comment: So it's not all dirty to get so many subscriptions everywhere? Maybe I can factorize something? Any pattern to follow?

Comment: I can't see any way to improve it.  At least not based on the example provided - you say you're getting "a lot" of subscriptions, but there's only two there and they're doing two different things.

Comment: Yes i mean through the app, I cannot copy/paste the whole app here ^^ I'll try to use | async, but I thougth there were a pattern or something else